# Does the customer have obligations under Know Your Customer?

Tags: credit-card, canada, know-your-customer

I have a credit card with a Canadian bank that I do no other business with at all - no accounts, no loans, no investments. They sent me a letter asking me to confirm that all the salient details are unchanged, and (in bold, twice) told me I could call a certain number or come into the branch. The letter didn't say "any branch" nor did it say which branch, and since all I have is a credit card I literally have no idea which of the 10-ish branches, all at least 45 minutes from me, it might want me to come to.

So I called and after waiting on hold (the number was just the generic telephone banking number) spoke to someone who confirmed this was a KYC thing and transferred me to someone who, on being told nothing had changed, said "great, fantastic, I just need you to come into the branch to confirm that." I assured her I was not going to do that, that I had already been a good sport about two long phone holds, and that I didn't even know what branch it was. I offered to send a signed letter. No, she said, you have to come in to the branch. She didn't offer to find out what branch it was, either. Eventually I said "hey, you're the ones subject to federal regulation, not me. If you're obliged to get information from me it's on you to come up with a process I find reasonable. I've called. I'm not coming in." And she said "well, you really need to come in" so I said "I don't think there's anything further to discuss" and ended the call.

Now, here's the thing: is any of this my problem? It's not, right? They are supposed to know me. I am not supposed to make myself known. I think maybe they might decide to cancel the card, and I can handle that if they do. I like having a card that's not associated with my main accounts, so if my main card is stolen or hacked I still have a card I can use. But I don't like it enough for a 90 minute round trip drive plus however long I have to sit around waiting to meet someone for whatever purpose it is they think I have to "pop into the branch" for. So if that's the consequence, I'm fine.

Are there other consequences?

Comment: My guess is they want to sell you on more services.  There can't be a requirement since all the stores with their branded credit cards don't do anything similar.

Comment: With Canadian banks they almost certainly don't care which branch you go to. Book an appointment at the one nearest to you, if you want to visit.

Answer (score 7):

It is not your problem in a sense that you are not legally obligated to come to the branch.

It is your problem in a sense that if they feel they cannot comply with the regulations, they'll have to close your account.

So if you're ok not doing business with them - you're fine.